# Fastest way to write multiple files in java

Tags: java, file, io

I have requirement where I need to write multiple input streams to a temp file in java. I have the below code snippet for the logic. Is there a better way to do this in an efficient manner?

```
final String tempZipFileName = "log" + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(tempZipFileName, "zip");
        final FileOutputStream oswriter = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        for (final InputStream inputStream : readerSuppliers) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[102400];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                oswriter.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            buffer = null;
            oswriter.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
            inputStream.close();
        }
```

I have multiple files of size ranging from 45 to 400 mb, for a typical 45mb and 360 mb files this method is taking around 3 mins on average. Can this be further improved?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are writing multiple input files to one output file.  The OS writing the output file to disk is likely to be the bottleneck, and it is not practical to parallelize that.   You may get a few percentage points improvement by using `ByteBuffer` and NIO file channels.  (Or something like `Files.copy` which should be using `ByteBuffer` under the hood ...)

Answer (score -1):

You could try a [BufferedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html)

As @StephenC replied is it unrelevant in this case to use a BufferedInputStream because the buffer is big enough.

I reproduced the behaviour on my computer (with an SSD drive). I took a 100MB file.

- It took 110ms to create the new file with this example.
- With an InputStreamBuffer and an OutputStream = 120 ms.
- With an InputStream and an OutputStreamBuffer = 120 ms.
- With an InputStreamBuffer and an
  OutputStreamBuffer = 110 ms.

I don't have a so long execution time as your's.

Maybe the problem comes from your `readerSuppliers` ?

Comment: It will make no difference.  The OP is already reading and writing using a large buffer.